# my wordpress child theme code is not working properly

Tags: wordpress

how are you today, i need your help. i am trying to make a child theme for twenty twenty one but i ran into a problem
i got it to load ok but is gven double headers and menus. i played around with but nothing
style.css. i am not great with php so i left that alone. here is the code i used.

```
    style.css
```

```css
    style.css
    Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-0ne_Child 
    Theme URL: http://yourdomain.com
    Description: Twenty Twenty-0ne_Child
    Theme Author: Your Name
    Author URL: http://yourdomain.com
    Template: twentytwentyone 
    Version: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

did you comment this ?

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-0ne_Child 
   Theme URL: http://yourdomain.com
    Description: Twenty Twenty-0ne_Child
    Theme Author: Your Name
    Author URL: http://yourdomain.com
    Template: twentytwentyone 
    Version: 1.0.0 
*/
```